# How is Python able to recognize which method is assigned to two different class methods that have the same name

Tags: python, oop, pygame

Hi I've been following tech with tim's videos on programming a simple 2D game. I understand the code he has written but I don't understand the logic of python is able to know which class to select.

'''

```
class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 10
        self.standing = True

    def draw(self, window):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0
        if not self.standing:
            if self.left:
                window.blit((walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3]), (self.x, round(self.y)))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif man.right:
                window.blit((walkRight[self.walkCount // 3]), (self.x, round(self.y)))
                self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            if self.right:
                window.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, round(self.y)))
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                window.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, round(self.y)))
                self.walkCount += 1


class projectile():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, (self.x, round(self.y)), self.radius)


def RedrawGameWindow():
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw
    man.draw(window)
```

later on there is a loop that adds the projectile's coordinates, color, direction ... to a list named bullets.

```
bullets.append(projectile((man.x + man.width//2), (man.y +man.height//2)),6, (0, 0, 0), facing)
```

However I don't understand why I can just call the draw method from the projectile class without first associating it to a variable and then calling .draw to select specifically the method from the projectile class.( and not the one from player class)

Comment: Read about [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) and [Method Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects)

Comment: `bullet.draw` doesn't do anything, you missed the braces `bullet.draw()`

Comment: `projectile(...)` constructs an instance object of the class `projectile`.  `player(...)` constructs an instance object of the class `player`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you have the line:

```
bullets.append(projectile((man.x + man.width//2), (man.y +man.height//2)),6, (0, 0, 0), facing)
```

and say 'there is a loop that adds the projectile's coordinates, color, direction ... to a list named bullets'.

That is not what that line is trying to do, it looks like you have a misplaced bracket. It should be:

```
bullets.append(projectile((man.x + man.width//2), (man.y + man.height//2), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing))
```

since the `, 6, (0, 0, 0), facing` are parameters to `projectile` not the `append()`.

It might be clearer if it was written something like this:

```
proj = projectile((man.x + man.width//2), (man.y + man.height//2), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing)
bullets.append(proj)
```

Which makes it clearer that the `projectile()` call creates a new instance of projectile and then in the next line it adds that new instance to the list of `bullets`. It can later go through all the projectiles by going through the items in the `bullet` list. It does not have to keep track of them separately.

All of the information specific to each projectile instance is saved within its internal state information. That is done by the classes `__init__()` method (which is the classes constructor) as you can see with the `self.XXXX = YYYY` statements.

When executing this loop:

```
for bullet in bullets:
    bullet.draw
```

it is going through that list and iterate through each projectile that it put on the bullet list previously and calling the draw routine for that specific instance.

Since projectile is a class and each item on the list is an instance of that class, each instance has all the methods in the projectile class, and the methods have access to the instance information (`self.x`, `self.y`, `self.width`, `self.heightt`, `self.vel`, etc.) through the `self` parameter.

So to answer your question, that is how python knows what method to call (it calls the one for the class) and how that method knows what it needs to about the instance to be able to do things.